# Eclipse Kepler not recognizing C++ header files

Tags: c++, eclipse, header-files, glfw

(ignore the actual code, it's copied from the GLFW website and I'm sure it'll be a pain to get working as well...)

I've been trying to link GLFW with a C++ Eclipse project. Eclipse won't even recognize the header file - after adding its folder to the project using "properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc." I try to inlucde it in my cpp file and get a "no such file or directory" error.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Ey5.png

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the proper way to do it, but I fixed the issue by including the folder not from "properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc." but from "properties -> C/C++ Build -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes"